# I need to retrieve the last 3 most recent dates

Tags: excel, vba, date, arraylist

I have a workbook with multiple sheets. I want to retrieve the last 3 most recent dates in a column and copy it into a summary sheet. I have on the summary sheet a column that lists the names of all the sheets in the workbook (Summary Worksheet: StepBrief).

Tail(j) is apart of an array list with the Worksheet Names listed on StepBrief.

NewestEntry is supposed to go to Tail(j)'s Worksheet and grab the most recent date in the 1st column. (This is where I'm having problems)

My last and most successful attempt is below. Any advice is **SUPPERR** appreciated. :)

```
Set Tail = New ArrayList

Dim DesiredTail As String
Dim FirstLine As String

   FirstLine = 6
   
For i = 0 To 20 Step 3 'Tail #/Number of Tails
    DesiredTail = Worksheets("StepBrief").Cells(i + 6, 3).Value
    Tail.Add DesiredTail

Next i

For j = 0 To 3 'Tail Tabs/Number of Tabs

    For k = 1 To 3 '# of Entries to Grab
    
    Dim NewestEntry As Double
        NewestEntry = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns(1))

    Worksheets(Tail(j)).Cells(NewestEntry, 1).Copy Worksheets("StepBrief").Cells(FirstLine, 4)  'Date
    Worksheets(Tail(j)).Cells(NewestEntry, 4).Copy Worksheets("StepBrief").Cells(FirstLine, 5)  'Code
    Worksheets(Tail(j)).Cells(NewestEntry, 5).Copy Worksheets("StepBrief").Cells(FirstLine, 6)  'Pilot
    Worksheets(Tail(j)).Cells(NewestEntry, 8).Copy Worksheets("StepBrief").Cells(FirstLine, 7)  'Start Up
    Worksheets(Tail(j)).Cells(NewestEntry, 11).Copy Worksheets("StepBrief").Cells(FirstLine, 8) 'Airboorne
    Worksheets(Tail(j)).Cells(NewestEntry, 14).Copy Worksheets("StepBrief").Cells(FirstLine, 9) 'Shutdown
            
        NewestEntry = NewestEntry - 1
        FirstLine = FirstLine + 1

        Next k
    Next j
```

Comment: In Excel > Options > enable Developer Tab and record a macro to see how VBA does it, then adapt/copy that macro code and make it work in your code. It'll be similar to this `Worksheets(TailValue(j)).Cells(k, 1).Value`

Comment: "This is where I'm having problems".  What problems?  Does your code error out?  Does it run, but give you an unexpected result?  What's currently happening?

Comment: "This is where I'm having problems".  What problems?  Does your code error out?  Does it run, but give you an unexpected result?  What's currently happening?